# Any example of a function which is discontinuous at each point in a deleted neighborhood of a point at which that function is differentiable?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, continuity

Let $f$ be a real (or complex) function defined on the segment $(a, b)$ of the real line, and let $p \in (a, b)$. If $f$ is differentiable at $p$, then of course $f$ is continuous at $p$ as well. (The converse may not hold.)

But can we have an example where $f$ is differentiable at $p$ but is *discontinuous* at all $x$ such that $x \in (c, d) \setminus \{ p \}$, for some real numbers $c$ and $d$ such that $$a < c < p < d < b?$$

Or, can we rigorously prove that the above situation cannot hold?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make things simpler, let $(a,b)=(-1,1)$ and $p=0$.  Now, consider the function:
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}x^2&x\in\mathbb{Q}\\-x^2&x\not\in\mathbb{Q}\end{cases}.
$$
This function is discontinuous everywhere except $0$, but it is differentiable at $0$ since the following limits are equal
$$
\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{h^2}{h}=0=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{-h^2}{h}.
$$

Comment: thank you very much. I've got a supplemental question: Exactly what kind of functions behave the way as does the function in your example? Is there any famous theorem in analysis in this regard?

Comment: There isn't a general form for these types of functions.  The result above is based on the squeeze theorem for derivatives (i.e., if you have $f(x)\leq g(x)\leq h(x)$ and $f'(0)=h'(0)$, then $g'(0)$ exists and is equal to $f'(0)$).