# Prob. 7, Chap. 5 in Baby Rudin: If $f^\prime(x)$, $g^\prime(x)$ exist, $g^\prime(x)\neq 0$ and $f(x)=g(x)=0$, ...

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

Here is Prob. 7, Chap. 5 in the book *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* by Walter Rudin, 3rd edition:

> Suppose $f^\prime(x)$, $g^\prime(x)$ exist, $g^\prime(x) \neq 0$, and $f(x) = g(x) = 0$. Prove that $$ \lim_{t \to x} \frac{ f(t) }{g(t)} = \frac{f^\prime(x)}{g^\prime(x)}.$$ (This holds also for complex functions.)

My Attempt:

> As $f(x) = g(x) = 0$ ans as $f^\prime(x)$ and $g^\prime(x)$ exist, with $g^\prime(x) \neq 0$, so we have 
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> \lim_{t\to x} \frac{f(t)}{g(t)} &= \lim_{t\to x} \frac{f(t) - 0 }{g(t) - 0 } \\
> &= \lim_{t \to x} \frac{ f(t) - f(x) }{ g(t) - g(x) } \\
> &= \lim_{t \to x} \frac{ \frac{f(t) - f(x)}{t-x}}{ \frac{g(t)-g(x)}{t-x}} \\
> &= \frac{\lim_{t \to x} \left(  \frac{f(t) - f(x)}{t-x} \right) }{ \lim_{t \to x} \left( \frac{g(t)-g(x)}{t-x} \right) } \\
> &= \frac{f^\prime(x)}{g^\prime(x)}.
> \end{align}
> $$

Is this reasoning correct? If so, I reckon the above calculation is valid for complex as well as real functions $f$ and $g$. Am I right?

I'm afraid we cannot resort to the Generalized Mean Value Theorem here even for real functions $f$ and $g$ because we have no information about the continuity of $f$ and $g$ in any interval containing $x$ or about the differentiability of these functions in a segment around $x$.

Please refer to a questions of mine at Math SE at the following link. 
[Any example of a function which is discontinuous at each point in a deleted neighborhood of a point at which that function is differentiable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2226149/any-example-of-a-function-which-is-discontinuous-at-each-point-in-a-deleted-neig)

Am I right?

Comment: Yes, it's correct. You don't need the mean value theorem, just the fact that the limit of a quotient is the quotient of the limits, when the denominator has limit $\ne0$.

Comment: @JaideepKhare thank you for your edit, but I'd prefer to keep the problem and chapter reference alongwith that of the text.

Comment: That Information isn't needed in the title, someone interested can easily get that information from the main body of the question... But ultimately it's your question and you can edit the title as you wish!

Comment: @JaideepKhare so nice of you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You surely can't invoke the mean value theorem.

The right tool is: suppose $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are functions defined in a punctured neighborhood of $x$ and that
$$
\lim_{t\to x}\alpha(t)=l,\qquad \lim_{t\to x}\beta(t)=m\ne0
$$
Then $\alpha(t)/\beta(t)$ is defined in a punctured neighborhood of $x$ and
$$
\lim_{t\to x}\frac{\alpha(t)}{\beta(t)}=\frac{l}{m}
$$
(which is what you essentially used).